# How can I see the order in which methods and functions are called in my application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

Is there any way in Xcode to see which functions get called in sequence, from start to end? (For example: the main function calls the an app delegate method, and so on.)

Can you do this using breakpoints, or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use instrument for that. You can access it from Xcode by asking Xcode to run your application using instrument.

Answer (score 0):

or you can type `bt` in xCode console

Answer (score 0):

If running in the iPhone Simulator, you can use a custom instrument build with DTrace for doing just that.  I provide the code and setup steps for building such an instrument in an article on MacResearch [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130203054550/http://macresearch.org/tuning-cocoa-applications-using-dtrace-custom-static-probes-and-instruments), or you can just download the custom instrument template [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/DTraceStartup.zip).

This particular template will list, in order of execution, every method called on every class from the launch of your application until it is ready to take user input.

Unfortunately, DTrace does not yet work on the iOS devices, so you can't run a custom instrument like this against your application running there.

(Update 10/4/2011) I propose what is probably a better way of handling this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app/7275049#7275049) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app), which uses breakpoints instead of DTrace.