# What is the execution order of methods on the startup of an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios

When an iOS application is first started, what methods are executed in what order?  Do some methods take priority over others?

Comment: If you want to observe the startup process yourself, my answer to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app) provides a way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a detail explanation for process from the following link,

http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/demystifying_iphone_app_startup

or you can take help from [here](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2159)