# lldb objc_msgSend tracing on OS X

Tags: macos, debugging, lldb

I'm tracing a OS X application, I hope can find a way like this way on iOS:

[lldb Xcode: error: 'printf' is not a valid command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693237/lldb-xcode-error-printf-is-not-a-valid-command/12695845#12695845)

Is there a way to do like this? I tried

```
expr -- (void)printf("[%s, %s]\n",(char *) object_getClassName(*(long*)($esp+4)), (char *) *(long *)($esp+8) )
```

I think OS X is used 64bit registers. So this command cann't work(Indeed, it doesn't work). How should I write this command? Or there is a simple way to do the same? Just tracing the class and method called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command you quote above is only correct for iOS Simulator apps which run as i386 processes on the Mac.  `$esp+4` means the first argument, `$esp+8` means the second argument passed in the i386 ABI.  On x86_64 and arm, the first few arguments are passed in registers with the `$arg1`, `$arg2` convenience names.  So try

```
p (void)printf("[%s, %s]\n", (char*)object_getClassName($arg1), $arg2)
```

for arm/x86_64 architectures.  (of course, `p` is an alias for `expr --` here - same thing, just less typing.)

Comment: It seems that printf doesn't print something in lldb(like (char*)object_getClassName($arg1), it works). How can I got a output print?

Comment: What are you debugging?  An iOS project running on a device?  A GUI Mac app (x86_64 presumably)?  A command line mac program using the command line lldb?  Attaching to a running process? You're running `printf` in your actual program when you do this so the output is going to go where ever `stdout` prints go ...

Comment: BTW you don't need to print via printf.  You could just say `p (char*) object_getClassName($arg1)` and `p $arg2` in lldb and avoid the hassle of where the program's output is going.

Comment: thx, I'm debugging a GUI Mac app with Xcode attaching. Now I got how to print. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JasonMolenda not sure if that still works. I get: "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10004005).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation."