# string of the @exp@ in breakpoint Log Message has only one first symbol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I need to trace my program. I made symbolic breakpoint:

[image]

Full string is:

```
"Class name is @*(char*)object_getClassName(*(long*)($esp+4))@"
```

But instead full class name I have only first one symbol on console i.e:

"Class name is 'U'"

Why? Have you any idea?

IDE : Xcode 4.6.2. LLDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it seems that you have an extra `*` before the `(char *)`. That dereferences the string to its first character.

**UPDATE:** The log message

```
Class name is @(char*)object_getClassName(*(long*)($esp+4))@
```

does also not work as intended because lldb prints the pointer value instead of the C string.
As a workaround, you can use the method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695845/1187415:

- Set the action to "Debugger Command" instead of "Log Message",
- Set the debugger command to

  ```
  expr -- (void)printf("Class name is %s\n",(char *) object_getClassName(*(long*)($esp+4)))
  ```

Comment: @stosha: What happens if you remove the first star: `"Class name is @(char*)object_getClassName(...)"`

Comment: Removing the first star would result in the pointer of string, not an instance of string.

Comment: @stosha: A C string *is* a pointer (to its characters). For example, `char *str = "UIKit"` is a C string, and `*str` gives the first character `'U'`. - But my first answer does not work as I could verify now (this could be a lldb bug). I have updated the answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: It should be noted that if you try this on a device you'll get an error. $esp is an x86 register.

Comment: @SnowCrash: That is correct. For arm and x86_64 one can use $arg1, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/16346300/1187415.