# Xcode Breakpoint: shortcut for file name or class name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

When setting a breakpoint in Xcode there is the `%B` shortcut. Placed into the "Log message" it will print the breakpoint name to the console. The `breakpoint name` will be the method name.

So creating a breakpoint in `- (void)viewDidLoad` will print

```
-viewDidLoad
```

When the breakpoint stops all is clear. But when the app continues after evaluating just `viewDidLoad` printed in the debug console won't tell which Class was called. `viewDidLoad` could be in every ViewController. So I add the class name to identify the location (see image).

To avoid having to type the full class name I use initials:
`MGA_OneViewController` becomes `OVC`

[image: Breakppint with Log Message "OVC %B"]

The `OVC %B` produces the output

```
OVG -viewDidLoad
```

and now the Class is known.

Typing three (or a few) letters is not a problem but is does require discipline to ensure the same acronym is used through out the class.

I found [a nice syntax](http://furbo.org/2013/04/11/logging-with-xcode-breakpoints/) but that is even longer, Craig uses
`p (void)NSLog(@"%s: %@", _cmd)`

Some related SO questions ([16661758](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662225/529243), [12695845](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695845/529243)) all use a rather long command, too long for me to remember.

So my questions are: is the there a percent shortcut for the class name? A `Percent-F` maybe?
Alternatively, is it possible to create a breakpoint template that will contain the expressions ready made?

Comment: Seems not. Bit of a shame as this would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `@[self class]@ %B` which, although not a formatter,  may be a little more compact than the alternatives listed in the original question.

Comment: That is easier to remember and does make it more consistent, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For swift you can use

```
@type(of:self)@
```