# Automatically logging method calls in iOS

Tags: ios, logging, method-call

Is there a way to automatically log the method calls in iOS projects in the console? something like:

```
[MainListTableViewController viewDidLoad]
[MainListTableViewController actionA]
[MainListTableViewController actionB]
```

I don't want to log system calls, and I don't want to manually put the NSlog in the code.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app) to enable a symbolic break point and this [blog](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/)

But couldn't figure out a proper solution.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why the question you linked is not a proper solution?

Comment: right, with enabling that break point you basically print a never-ending list and looks like the application never starts running, i.e., the first screen doesn't comes up. I disable the break point and the application start working. But with that break point I wait for 10 min and it is still printing out a list in the console while the first screen doesn't show up. I am not sure if it takes so long and I have to wait for a longer time to have the application ready to interact with. Also I want to avoid system calls.

Comment: I ended up using NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled environment variable  http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/