# iOS user methods/function trace

Tags: ios, methods, trace

Is there any way to collect the functions/methods, defined by developer (not system calls), that are called during runtime and execution of an iPhone app?

For example while dynamically running an iPhone app, and clicking on a button I want to collect functions A, B, C, .... that are written by developers and are called. And see which method is called by which method.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a great way to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled environment variable dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `NSThread`'s `callStackSymbols`.

Documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/callStackSymbols)