# Monitor Method Start/Exit in Swift/Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a way to automatically monitor "method enter" and "method exit" in Swift or Objective-C

Comment: What do you mean method enter or method exit? Just print a line at the beginning and end of a method?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270502/how-to-log-all-methods-used-in-ios-app

Comment: Kendel - I want something automatic that will capture all of my methods
gabuh - This will give me only method enter without method exit and only on debug version