# How can I print the name of the object / interface with Xcode breakpoint log?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Xcode debug log can print the method name using `%B` and the hit count using `%H`. How can I print the interface / object  name using similar notation ? Preferably without the use of NSLog / debugger command.

Comment: have you tried NSLog(@"%@", [yourObject class]); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that `@[self class]@` log message will do the trick. I am not sure its validity on every occasion. I am using `@[self class]@ %B %H` for my purpose. I also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7270502/2182047) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7275049/2182047) but it was not just working on Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is

```
NSLog("My file is %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__]);
```

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` contains the class name and method, which may suit you better than FILE.

Comment: I was expecting an answer without using NSLog.

Comment: OK Well if not NSLog, how do you want it? You could use the same parameters and call printf instead, for example.

Comment: Like the one which doesn't need a debugger action but a only a log action. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29774554/2182047). Do you have any similar answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Every Objective-C object can be printed with `%@`. `NSLog(@"%@", someObject)` will print object's [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description). You can override `description` method for your classes to provide more detailed info. Look at this note too: [Improved logging in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1669/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the breakpoint's debugger command action, you can put:

```
expr printf ("[%s %s]\n", (char *)object_getClassName(self), _cmd)
```

This will output, e.g.  `[SomeClass someMethod:]`

Answer (score -1):

You can print anything using `NSLog();`

Say, for example, you have an

```
NSString *myString = @"qdfsqsdfqsdf";
```

This is an important string you would like to log, you'll just type :

```
NSLog(@"My important string : %@", myString);
```

If that is what you're asking, I'm surprised you dont' know that if you already know about `%B` & `%H`.  Am I answering your question or do you need a bit more?